# mySQL Create Procedure error + general mysql help

Tags: mysql

Hi 
I'm very very new at MySQL and was wondering if anyone could help me out.
I'm trying to build a procedure for my database and am using the following code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `createuser`(username VARCHAR(100), password VARCHAR(100), email VARCHAR(100)) BEGIN

DECLare returnValue int;

IF EXISTS(SELECT 'True' FROM User_Table WHERE(User_Username = username OR User_Email = email))  
    BEGIN     
        SET returnValue = 0;
    END; 
ELSE
    BEGIN
       SET returnValue = 1;
       INSERT into User_Table(User_Username, User_Password,User_Email) VALUES(username, password,email) 
    END; END;
```

I'm getting a error on the BEGIN after the if statement. The error is "Bad syntax near "BEGIN SET returnvalue = 0; END ELSE;

Could you please tell me if im using the IF statement correctly in a mysql sence. It seems to work fine on a MSSql server but not on a Mysql.

Would it also be possible to point me in the direction of some good tutorials for this kinda stuff as the main MYSQL website isn't particularity user friendly.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
IF statement
    BEGIN
        commands;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        commands;
    END
```

use

```
IF statement THEN
    commands;
ELSE
    commands;
END IF;
```

Here is how I would write your procedure (changes may be a mixture of cosmetic changes and actual changes; suggest experimenting to find out which are which)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `createuser` ( IN username VARCHAR(100),
                                IN password VARCHAR(100),
                                IN email VARCHAR(100)
                                )
BEGIN
    DECLARE returnValue INT;
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM User_Table
        WHERE User_Username = username OR User_Email = email
    ) THEN
        SET returnValue = 0;
    ELSE
        SET returnValue = 1;
        INSERT INTO User_Table
        (User_Username, User_Password, User_Email)
        VALUES
        (username, password, email);
    END IF;
END;
```

You don't appear to be doing anything with the variable `returnValue`. You might need to declare this as `OUT` or `INOUT`, depending on what you want to do with it. I haven't got experience of using return values for stored procedures.